# What is Dell ControlPoint?

Tags: windows-xp, dell-latitude

I just bought a computer from a friend, and there is a program on it called "Dell ControlPoint." Does anyone know what it is or what it's for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You might find this interesting](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/latit/en/dell_controlpoint_specsheet.pdf).  (It's the first Google result for "Dell ControlPoint"...)

Also this link

[Fix, Connect to and Learn About Dell™ ControlPoint™ Connection Manager](http://support.dell.com/support/topics/global.aspx/support/kcs/document?c=us&l=en&s=gen&docid=DSN_356970&isLegacy=true)

Comment: LOL...that was funny.

Comment: @Purmou - I wasn't really trying to be snarky or funny, but sometimes it does bear saying. :)